# Creating hair follicles at selected vertices

Tags: python, maya, vertex

I'm trying to write a code that creates `hair follicles` in Autodesk Maya at the selected vertices, my code works, but it creates all the follicles at the same vertex when I have more than one selected.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

sel = cmds.ls( sl = 1, fl = 1 )

for i in sel:
    pp = cmds.pointPosition( sel[ 0 + 1 ], w = 1 )
    fol = cmds.createNode( 'follicle' )
    cmds.move( pp[ 0 ], pp[ 1 ], pp[ 2 ], fol )
```

My logic is that when it loops back around for the second selected vertex the `pointPosition` will find the location of that vertex, create the node, and move it there. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import maya.cmds
sel = cmds.ls(sl=1, fl=1)
for i in sel:
    pp = cmds.pointPosition(i, w=1)
    fol = cmds.createNode('follicle')
    cmds.move(pp[0], pp[1], pp[2], fol)
```

Comment: Man, that was so dumb... Thanks very much!